# Word for software which has been killed or is no longer supported

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

When describing a piece of software on a list I have the following information:

SoftwareName

Released: 2013-12-12

????: 2014-12-12

The ???? is like the opposite of Released. Maybe I could use *killed* (but that is too strong), or *no longer supported*, but I would prefer a single word.

Comment: "obsoleted" might work, depending how much you dislike verbing.

Comment: Are you describing the situation Windows XP is in now? Or is your situation different?

Comment: Software features that are no longer supported are [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) and then removed. The software itself is usually described by whatever state it's actually in: e.g., *unsupported* if help (support) is no longer available for an old version, or *abandoned* if the maintainers no longer work on it, etc. Source: Software developer :)

Comment: Other words you might enjoy: [Abandonware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abandonware), [Sunsetting](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/sunsetting)

Comment: If there's a newer version which *is* supported then you might want "superceded"

Comment: @Rupe There is no such word as *∗superceded*. It **sits** atop; it does not **go** atop. That is because it comes from Latin *super-* + *sedēre* meaning “to sit”. There is no Latin *cēdĕre* (which would be the *go* sense, as in all the others) involved in that word at all. It is ***supersede***.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, "sunsetting" is worthy of getting into an answer, IMO.

Comment: @Jaydles, good suggestion; I added it.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Why cudgel verbing? Great writers back to Shakespeare verbed themselves silly. Hamlet telling where the body of Polonius may be found: "... if indeed you find him not within this month, you shall **nose** him as you go up the stairs into the lobby."

Comment: I vote for "truecrypted". http://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/26pxol/truecrypt_is_dead/

Comment: My answer is below, I'd go with 'Deprecated', as a professional in the field.

Comment: @Robusto, I don't mind verbing, and I'd use *obsolete* as a verb in this context. But some people don't like it, and I wouldn't force OP to use it if he is one of those people.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

It depends on your precise meaning, and the intended audience.

It could mean ending:

- Feature updates
- Non-security bug fixes
- Security fixes
- Customer support / troubleshooting
- Service, in the case of SaaS (software as a service)

Sometimes there will be different dates for ending each of these.

---

For a general-use single-word verb to mirror *released*, I suggest ***discontinued***. That is, releases, support, etc. (whatever it is that you mean) are no longer continuing.

But I would prefer [***end of life***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-life_(product)), which though not a single word (unless you count *end-of-life* or *EOL*) is a common industry term, and usually denotes an end to updates or fixes. This is, for example, what the operating system [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) uses: "Release date" and "End of life date".

---

Some other possibilities:

- *abandoned* - implies the ending was unplanned
- *deactivated* / *defunct* - accurate if the software is actually no longer functioning
- *decommissioned* / *retired* - might work, though I would use this for when something actually stops being used, as when a particular company, user, or specific system is no longer using it
- *deprecated* - describes software as replaced, or not officially recommended. This precedes its complete removal. This term is not widely used outside of software libraries (and software developers).
- *obsolete* - not great, as it describes the need or use for the software, not the state of development or support; software can become practically obsolete long before any planned support date
- *sunsetted* - a sunset is actually a period of time of limited support, so it doesn't fit a single date as you have requested. This term is frequently used, e.g. Google Reader
- *terminated* - good, though if you didn't like *killed*, this might also be too strong
- *unsupported* - good, though not all software is ever "supported" in the way some may think: regular bug fixes, support staff, etc.

Comment: I was surprised no one else had mentioned deprecated

Comment: Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/364, for the use–mention distinction, please use an italic face not a bold  one. It makes the page look too heavy otherwise, and furthermore runs counter to typographic convention both on this  site and in scholarly works.

Comment: @PaulDraper “Authoritative”? Things here work by consensus not by fiat. But yes, [those of us who try to keep the site clean](http://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all) certainly all abide by that advice.  It looks better, produces a more pleasant textual color in the technical sense, and abides by the standard practices of typographic convention in all formal written works.

Comment: I won’t make a blanket statement that one should never under any circumstances use bold, but one needs to assess it the same double-penalty when computing its Lawler-weight, just as one does for an all-caps portion.   It looks pretty obnoxious.  If that’s the goal, so be it, but it should not be used for the use–mention distinction.

Comment: @tchrist, ah, I understand the use-mention distinction, and did not intend to use it for that. Believing it to improve clarity, I bolded words that were direct one-word answers/solutions, i.e. *released* was not in bold, since it was not a solution. Thank you.

Comment: I like *discontinued* the best. Can we put some more emphasis on that word? Italics just doesn't make it stand out. You can put it in a line by itself, I guess.

Comment: @justhalf, I had it bolded, but tchrist edited that out. I'll probably put that back.

Comment: *Deprecated* isn't appropriate, but is worth mentioning. If a feature is deprecated, then its authors no longer approve of its continued use, but do still support it. Quite often this means support will be discontinued in the future, and they recommend people should change to other methods now, in preparation of that, but some things have been deprecated for decades.

Comment: @PaulDraper: He's been doing it on loads of questions lately. Gotta keep up with those "scholarly works". Would be nice if some more thought went into it though.

Comment: "End of life" is what happened to Windows XP.

Comment: "Sunset" refers to a period of lingering support for previously-supported users. Use of this term tends to suggest that the vendor has internalized problems with support, that there may be a dedicated legacy-support department whose personnel motivate such euphemism. "Discontinued but supported" (or "support contracts honored") are far more understandable.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, agreed. FYI, in my experience a common problem is that someone puts a date on it, and you don't know if it is the beginning or the end of the sunset.

Comment: thats a lot of pseudonyms for `dead` or `dying`.

Answer (score 41):

*Deprecated* is often used to describe lower-level APIs/function/libraries that should not be used going forward. See wikipedia on [software deprecation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation).

Comment: Deprecation refers more to features and programming methods than an end-user product itself. Unsurprising that this has many upvotes since this is a featured question on a site popular among software developers, but in the context of the OP (opposite of "released"), words like "retired" or "end-of-life" fit much better.

Comment: @nmclean yes I did mention that its more relevant to lower-level software components or methods. However, I don't believe the original question specified "end-user product" (i.e. collection) or a list of software pieces (e.g. libraries) where I think its valid.

Comment: @nmclean An entire software package can get deprecated, see e.g. [HAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_(software)#Deprecated).

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, it is appropriate for HAL. By "programming methods", I do mean entire libraries as well as individual algorithms. The point is that when we are talking about "releases" and "support" (as in OP), we usually refer to end-user applications. "Deprecated" is inappropriate here because it belongs to the domain of programming.

Comment: Whole software packages are "deprecated" all the time.  This is the correct answer.

Comment: @paqogomez *deprecation* means that the API is still supported, but that its further use is discouraged with the understanding that the API will be removed in a later version. So I don't really see how this fits the description. Win XP was deprecated (you certainly didn't see anyone at MS telling people to buy XP instead of Win7) very long before it reached end of life. Although I agree with nmclean that it's not something that I'd use to describe whole products to begin with, wrong domain.

Answer (score 31):

Use [end-of-life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-life_%28product%29); that's standard in the industry, in my experience.

Comment: "Standard" has a meaning besides that something is common practice. I don't believe there is a formalized, legal definition of *end-of-life* so the term is not literally an industry standard.

Comment: Point. Perhaps I should have said that it is "standard in the industry".

Comment: @Potatoswatter, how about saying: that's the de-facto standard in the industry

Answer (score 12):

I've heard *sunset* as a more positive sounding alternative to the common *end-of-life*. Both are pretty common in software engineering terms.

Comment: I never came across this one, as a seasoned developer. Good to know.

Comment: "Sunset" is a bit vague for a software product. Usually you hear it in relation to laws and rules/regulations. If absolutely nothing more is to be done with a product, enhancement- or support-wise, my preference is _withdrawn_.

Comment: I've _never_ heard this. The closest I've come is "twilight years" in the context of a greying individual :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: the term “sunset” got a fair bit of media exposure a couple of years back when [Yahoo! used it in a slide that was leaked](http://mashable.com/2010/12/16/leaked-slide-shows-yahoo-is-killing-delicious-other-web-apps/)

Comment: This sounds like meaningless euphemism.

Answer (score 9):

Different people use different things here, so which term below would work best in your specific situation is going to vary depending on your intended use of it.

- decommissioned
- uninstalled
- discontinued
- deactivated
- shut down / shut off
- deleted
- retired
- retired from service
- became unsupported
- passed its contractual end-of-life cut-off date

Comment: I'd argue that "uninstalled", "shut down/off", "deleted", "deactivated" aren't "the opposite of Released", as requested. "Discontinued" is a possibility, as is "retired/retired from service". Your final two seem to hit the mark.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't include [*deprecated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation), given that OP said *killed off* was "too strong". I know it's a lot "weaker" than, say, *discontinued, deactivated*, but in some contexts it's pretty close to *unsupported*.

Comment: Deprecated is used more for software parts.

Answer (score 6):

The software industry term for obsolescence is *deprecate*:

- deprecated
- deprecation

Whereas, IT management tend to use the term "obsolete*:

- obsoleted
- obsolescence

The software industry term for cessation of effectiveness without obsolescence is *expiry*:

- expired
- expiration

The terms can be applied to

- a whole piece of software or application
- a software licensing or parts of it
- features in a software
- modules in a software or application
- functions, parts of code, entities, objects, methodology, technique, design, architecture.

A feature, entity, portion of a software, or the version of the software is said to be

- *deprecated/obsolete* when it is still in use but has been superseded by a recommended alternative.
- *expired* when it is pulled from release and is no longer permitted to be used, or that the software itself has time-bombed itself, a feature, entity, portion of itself from being useful.

Examples

- The licence on the module will be expiring in 30 days.
- We have planned obsolescence for deployment of Ubuntu 1204 next year.
- The version released Jan 15 will expire on July 15.
- We are deprecating all iMac deployments in favour of Linux and Windows 8.
- When I tried to install the software, a dialog would pop up saying "*This release has expired on Apr 30, 2013. Please contact IT support. Your attempt to use expired software on workstation WSBay17 under user name WA5\Gunasekarn has been duly noted.*"

Software: Skorn Shell's Engels
Version: 0.9.2-snapshot
Release Date: 2010-09-20
Expiry Date: 2015-09-20
Deprecated: 2014-04-12
Deprecated by version: 1.0.1

Comment: Deprecated and obsolete aren't entirely synonymous. Obsolete means that it is antiquated and that there is a preferred modern alternative. Deprecated means that it is suggested you seek a more up to date method but acknowledges that certain situations will still make use of the technology that is on its way out. To Simplify: Obsolete means it's been replaced, Deprecated means it's on its way out.

Comment: When you go to a management meeting with no programmers - you never would use the term "deprecated", otherwise "huh"s all around. You have to use "obsolescence". Because in management lingo, "obsolescence" is a system that is still running but they badly wish to retire because has been superseded, but unfortunately still has some loose shoe laces tied elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Also consider:
• *[defunct](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/defunct#Adjective)*, “No longer in use, inactive” (plus some other related senses),
• *[obsolete](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obsolete#Adjective)*, “No longer in use; gone into disuse; disused or neglected”
• *[withdrawn](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/withdrawn#Adjective)*, ie taken back, taken out of use

Answer (score 3):

*Abandoned* (mostly open source) and *end-of-life (EOL)* (mostly commercial) are most used.

The software/system development lifecycle (SLDC) calls it *disposition* on some sheets I have seen.

Comment: [Please ‘never’ use   or ˋbackticksˋ on ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722).

Comment: I do not understand the question. My edit certainly does use markdown markup.

Comment: Follow the link for why.  And please look up the distinction between *for example* and *that is*.

Comment: That, too, has been discussed. There are issues relating to literalities.

Comment: This comment thread makes so little sense. Were half the comments summarily deleted?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the end of software is not as distinct as it's start. On a legacy device old software might run just fine long after the developers have moved on and forgotten about it. The exact end of the software's life (or life cycle) depends largely on the attitudes of the person naming the software's demise.

The choice of word(s) reflects a great deal on the attitude of the community, the developer and the model of deployment. For example a commercial software company might talk of "end of production" as if it were a physical product (which if sold mainly on CD/DVD it might seem to be) whereas a company that makes more money from support talks about the "end of life" or "end of support" time frame.

Thus there are terms that talk about ongoing support and bugfixes, ongoing development (beyond just bugfixes) and just general appropriateness for any given task. Which is why you get a range of answers from withdrawn (no longer offered as a product) to Obsolete (something better exists, like an upgrade or a better solution).

When the software is still available but it has reach "End of Life" (de facto term) where I have worked we often call it "Retired" which means that you can use it if you want but we accept no bug reports and you do so at your own risk. Sometimes it's "Retired / Replaced with" sometimes written as "Retired/Obsolete. Upgrade to NewSoftwareTitle". However that suggests that there is an upgrade path albeit a nonstandard one.

Some firms are fond of "End of Support" or variants like that. In which case "Superseded by" is commonly given if there is something else.

The open source community sometimes lists software as "abandoned" which means that there is no one maintaining it anymore. Or if the developer is taking their time to put anything out - it might be described as "inactive" which can be effectively the same thing. This however indicates something entirely different to software that has been shelved or withdrawn which suggests more that the developers are the ones calling the shots, so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for slang, I'd go with either

- Betamaxed

or

- XP'd

Two now obsolete technologies, although technically betamaxed can mean

> When a technology is overtaken in the market by inferior but better marketed competition.

Runners up include

- Defunct
- Deprecated
- 86'd

Comment: I like `Betamaxed`  Good option. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use *terminated* as in *terminator*. :)

Answer (score -2):

Technically, the product is not dead, just not supported/active, and for that reason "floruit' applies **[floruit](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/1352410)** because it refers to the active years:

> ... a period of time during which a person, school, movement or
>   even species was active or flourishing. It is the third person,
>   singular, perfect tense, indicative, active form of the Latin verb
>   "florere" — "to flourish".

The term for its lack of support is

> [**Abandonware**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abandonware)  is a product, typically software, ignored by its owner and
>   manufacturer, and for which no product support is available. Although
>   such software is usually still under copyright, the owner may not be
>   tracking or enforcing copyright violations. Abandonware is a variant
>   of the general concept of **[orphan works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_works)**.

&

> **[Legacy code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_code)** is source code that relates to a no-longer supported

Note: Microsoft Lifecycle Policy refers to Windows 95 (an unsupported product)  as **"obsolete"** or **[support retired](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/lifecycle)** -see link for chart of 'Desktop operating systems/Date of availability/Support retired' dating format

Comment: I don't think one generally refers to a software product as "flourishing". Not a bad answer but I don't think it relates to this particular field of endeavor.

Comment: @MattGutting, despite buzzwords like 'software archaeology', data is never dead, programs are adapted,changed,open-sourced, copyright restricted...they are a true zombie

Comment: Then it's settled... the software has been **zombified**!

Comment: Abandonware has a very specific meaning, and it's NOT just end of support. It means the product has been released to the public, without support, and typically without the source, effectively releasing the product into the public domain, the creator abandoning all rights to it.

Comment: Ditto legacy code is NOT what is meant here. Legacy code is code that's old, usually nobody around any more who has experience with how it works, but is still part of existing systems so it has to be maintained. It's definitely NOT unmaintained, unsupported, code. It's just a maintenance PITA.

Comment: @jwenting  the links disagree with your learned opinion -as the millions who have read them

Comment: @ThirdNews that'd be news to the millions who've actually had to maintain legacy code...

Comment: @jwenting, I would be careful about conflating "abandonware" and "public domain". Just because a developer/maintainer/copyright holder _appears_ to have walked away from a project does **NOT** mean they have relinquished all rights to it. They have to do that _explicitly_ for it to go into the public domain.

Comment: @PhilPerry and I do just that... "has been released to the public", an explicit act. Not "pirated so much it's lost all economic potential"...

Comment: @jwenting, then it's not really "abandonware" so much as "released into the PD". Where I've usually seen "abandonware" is something where the author/owner has simply stopped showing up or doing anything with it. Many places have a license clause you agree to when you contribute add-ons, mods, plug-ins, etc. that if you can't be contacted for some length of time, ownership and copyright revert to the main project or repository. Not all do this, so it depends upon the particular license used. It's impolite to simply take a project without contact, and sometimes a copyright violation.