# Word describing an outdated and no longer updated software package

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word describing a software package that has not been updated for a long time, and although it still works with new versions of the underlying software, bugs have not been fixed for years, and no new features have been added.

I found [this similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177327/word-for-software-which-has-been-killed-or-is-no-longer-supported), however, none of the words from the answer really seem to match, because the software package still exists and works, but just has not been updated in a long time. So it was not retired, or replaced, or terminated, or deprecated, or sunsetted.

"Unsupported" would somewhat match, but this essentially applied to a huge number of similar packages which are typically not officially supported. "Abandoned" sounds a bit harsh to me, as I would use the word in a document that the original author of the package might get to see at some point.

I was thinking about something like "obsolete" or "outdated", but this sort of seems to imply that there exists something newer, or better replacing the old package, which is not the case.

Comment: I've seen it called "abandonware" -- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abandonware

Comment: You could just say it's ***defunct***, since unlike ***obsolete / outdated*** this doesn't particularly imply it's been replaced by something newer / better.

Comment: You did not say in what context you need this. Perhaps *legacy software* might fit.

Comment: You say "abandoned" seems a bit harsh, but I say it seems perfectly appropriate.

Comment: "Legacy" and "out of support"/"no longer supported" are terms I hear frequently for this (and I work in IT).  Or even "past end of life".  Notice these are different from "unsupported" in that they imply there was support before.

Comment: I'm thinking the term "stable" might actually apply.

Comment: *No longer supported*

Comment: How about not currently maintained? This indicates it’s not yet abandoned or unsupported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Unsupported

Is the term usually applied to this type of software. *Unsupported* in the software world, usually means 'end of life', and 'no more updates'.

*End of life* and *unsupported* are synonymous in this context.

For example, from:

***[Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10736/windows-what-does-it-mean-if-not-supported)***

> What does it mean if Windows isn't supported? An unsupported version
> of Windows will no longer receive software updates from Windows
> Update. These updates include security updates that can help protect
> your PC from harmful viruses, spyware, and other malicious software
> which can steal your personal information. Windows Update also
> installs the latest software updates to improve the reliability of
> Windows—such as new drivers for your hardware.
>
> Will I still be able to use Windows after support ends?
>
> Yes, even if you have an unsupported version of Windows XP or Windows
> Vista, Windows will continue to start and run. You just won't be able
> to receive software updates from Windows Update any longer.

***[Berkley Information Security Policy](https://security.berkeley.edu/faq/isp-security-notices/operating-system-unsupported)***

> Security best practices...require the use of supported software for
> which the vendor will make security updates available in a timely
> fashion. As vendors are unable to support all previous versions of
> software, older programs are dropped from support and must be upgraded
> or removed from the network.

***[Australian Government (stay smart online)](https://www.staysmartonline.gov.au/alert-service/stop-using-unsupported-software-and-apply-new-security-updates)***

> Stop using unsupported software and apply new security updates
>
> You should retire all vendor products that have reached end of life,
> meaning they are no longer supported. These products typically do not
> receive any patches that protect against newer viruses, spyware or
> other malicious software and may not be subject to technical support.

Comment: No. Unsupported doesn’t include the poster’s stipulation that the program has bugs. Just because unsupported Microsoft software has, doesn’t mean that Wibble 2000 has.

Comment: If software has bugs, they will not be resolved if the software is unsupported. Unsupported encompasses both the requirement described in the title of the question : "Word describing an outdated and no longer updated software package" and the additional stipulation that the software may have bugs. Bug or no bugs. Unsupported does indeed answer this question, I happen to come from an IT background also, so from an experiential point of view, can also confirm this is the correct term, although I trust the above explanation makes the linguistic case clear also.

Comment: Question states categorically “bugs haven’t been fixed for years”. Unsupported software may be completely bug-free. Your answer may be the closest, and useful to the poster, but it doesn’t satisfy his criteria. As usual people are looking for words that don’t exist

Comment: @David "Software is bug-free when its last user has died."

Comment: @user888379 — There's no answer to that.

Comment: @David True, but I was pointing out that "bug-free" frequently isn't a useful definiendum ...

Comment: @user888379 There is a difference between formal logic and real life. If the poster had not added “Bugs have not been fixed for years” then your statement of the real-life situation would be pertinent. But he has made this an additional condition for the word he requires, implicitly indicating that there are KNOWN bugs. This accepts the Logical possibility that a bug-free program can exist, or at least is different from your generalization that all programs have bugs (and which I can deny - hello world - and you cannot prove) and invalidates the answer.

Answer (score 3):

legacy software

And I am most definitely not a programmer.

For example: [legacy software](https://www.stromasys.com/2016/07/an-overview-of-legacy-software-and-legacy-systems/)

What is legacy software?

> Legacy software is software that has been around a long time and still
>   fulfills a business need. It is mission critical and tied to a
>   particular version of an operating system or hardware model (vendor
>   lock-in) that has gone end-of-life. Generally the lifespan of the
>   hardware is shorter than that of the software. As time goes on, the
>   hardware gets harder to maintain but is kept because it is installed
>   and (for now) working and has proven too complex and/or expensive to
>   replace.

Comment: It's like Bjarne Stroustrup said, "legacy software" often differs from its would-be replacement, by working and scaling! 

Answer (score 2):

**[Deprecate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deprecate)**

> 3. *Computers* To mark (a component of a software standard) as obsolete to warn against its use in the future so that it may be phased out.

[Source: The Free Dictionary]

Comment: This is an active designation not one of quiet abandonment.

Comment: This is usually applied to features of a programming language or an API (Application Programming Interface)  I’ve not seen it applied to a program or application.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the answer to this is
obsolecent     ie it still works but is not the current version.
Everthing we buy from TV's to computers or software becomes obsolescent as soon as a new model comes out.

Comment: The correct spelling is *obsolescent*. Please backup your answer with references, e.g. from a dictionary.

Comment: A thing cannot become obsolescent, only obsolete. And OP explicitly ruled out obsolete.

Comment: Have a look at this link

Comment: Have a look at this link   http://grammarist.com/usage/obsolescent-obsolete/         It specifies the difference between obsolescent and obsolete.   An object becomes obsolescent and then obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

How 'bout collectable, antique, historic, or other term indicating someone still thinks it has value.  I like "antique computers" or "antique electronics".  Maybe because I'm antique.

Comment: Can you show that this is in common usage for outdated software?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen **Deprecated** and **End of Life** used for software that is past the useful life or no longer able to supported by the manufacturer/developer.

Comment: Hello, Dan. The first term was already provided as a verb in another answer. Would you be able to improve your answer by explaining more thoroughly and providing some references?